# retracting moderator attention/recommend deletion

Tags: discussion

Today I reviewed the [first revision of this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/102486/revisions) answer. I recommended deletion, which AFAIK results in it getting queued for moderator attention.

My recommendation might not be entirely correct, the answer was not invalid per se.

What is important is that the answer was edited afterwards, and only because someone commented on the automatically added comment ("This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique ...") did I notice that the answer was changed. And changed into something that would no longer need moderator attention.

I did not find a way to retract this recommendation, (like you can do with—no longer applicable—votes).
What is the proper way to proceed in this case?

- should I try and notify the moderators
- should I remove the automatically generated comment

As I indicated: without the comments I would never have noticed that this low-quality answer was changed after I had reviewed it. I would have liked a notification based on the edit of something I recommended to be deleted (even though I don't know how to proceed to change my recommendation), if nothing else to encourage the Answerer that things have indeed improved.

Comment: Of course my biggest concern is to get another declined moderator attention flag ;-)

Comment: I'm aware that sometimes mods check the revision history and/or deletion of the post clear the flags were cast.

Comment: You can put a comment under the item: "I changed my mind about recommending deletion".

Answer (score 3):

Read up on how the low quality review queue works:

[What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues)

Choosing Recommend Deletion does not send it to moderators.  It just marks your vote on the review.  Once six such votes are received, the answer will then be deleted.  One vote for "looks good" will end the review and the answer is left alone.  Therefore, no harm was done by your vote.  Five votes for recommend deletion will still have no effect if one vote is cast for "looks good."  The vote cannot be changed after you cast it, so there is nothing to do now.

Should you delete the comment?  Yes, I would delete it now that it is no longer accurate.  It keeps the site clean when obsolete comments are removed.  Moderators can see that the deleted comment used to be there.  They see deleted things as being highlighted in light red.

Declined flags are a different matter.  You would have had to use the menu marked "flag" to set a flag for moderator attention.

Comment: does not answer question which is about flags

Answer (score 2):

"Recommend deletion" does not trigger a mod flag (or any other flag), there is no need to notify the moderators. You cannot retract a deletion recommendation. You should delete your comment, as it is now obsolete, and perhaps add a comment thanking the poster for addressing the feedback and improving the post.